# The house with two rooms

Tags: algebraic-topology

In chapter $0$ of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, when he explains why the house with two rooms is contractible, the first step is to consider a closed $\epsilon$-neighborhood $N(X)$ of $X$, where $X$ is the house with two rooms. I don't know why it is necessary to consider $N(X)$ instead of just $X$. There is probably a very simple reason but I just started to learn this, so I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really necessary, as $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $N(X)$. If the takeaway is that $X$ is contractible, it doesn't matter whether we look at $X$ or $N(X)$.

However, the way Hatcher argues that $X$ is contractible is by showing that $N(X)$ is *homeomorphic* to $D^3$. Homeomorphisms are more strict than homotopy equivalence, and $X$ is *not* homeomorphic to $N(X)$. So if you accept his argument for why $N(X)$ is homeomorphic to $D^3$, then in particular $N(X)$ is contractible. But this implies $X$ is contractible since $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $N(X)$.